# Why is Unity 5.6 displaying launch image wrong on iOS?

Tags: unity, ios

I updated from Unity 5.5.0p3 to 5.6.0f3, and I have no idea what's causing this. The iOS launch image which looked like this:

[image]

Now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in 5.6 which causes transparency to not be imported. Install the newest patch release. Then reimport the affected file(s). Then try the build.

Comment: So you mean get a 5.6.0p# release instead of the f3 release I have?

Comment: Yep, try that. Just had another look and the issue was in 5.5 (but the later releases) not in 5.6. But it could still solve the problem.

Comment: 5.6.0p4 same problem. :(

Comment: Why don't you try using a newer version of unity(like unity 2017.3)? Is it because of scripts/assets? You would benefit a lot in terms of performance and features!